# Cassandra DB: Storing XML-Files in Cassandra Database possible?

Tags: java, xml, database, cassandra

I have here a bunch of XML-files which I like to store in a Cassandra database. Is there any possiblity out there to manage that or do I have to parse and reform the XML-files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly store them as a blob or text but you will not be able to query the individual fields within the XML files. One other thing you'd want to be cautious of is payload size and partition size. Cassandra in general isn't really designed as an object store but depending on payload size and desired query functionality, you may either have to parse/chunk them out or look for an alternative solution.